# Connection timed out (Connection timed out). ERRORCODE=-4499, SQLSTATE=08001 from glue

Tags: python, jdbc, db2, aws-glue

I created one glue job to fetch data from IBM on-prem db2 and i downloaded jar file `db2jcc4.jar` from google and added this dependency path in glue job also but i am getting connection timedout error. i connected db2 from sql developer app with same jar file it's successfully connected. but through glue i am getting below error.

```
An error occurred while calling o102.load. [jcc][t4][2043][11550][4.26.14] Exception java.net.ConnectException: Error opening socket to server cbfnd847/10.241.21.221 on port 50,000 with message: Connection timed out (Connection timed out). ERRORCODE=-4499, SQLSTATE=08001
```

i created security groups with all traffic as well but not working.

glue job:

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job

## @params: [JOB_NAME]
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)
db_username = "nmporl"
db_password = "Abcd23"
db_url = "jdbc:db2://cbfnd847:50000/ABC10938"
jdbc_driver_name ="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver"
table_name = "table01"


# Connecting to the source
df = glueContext.read.format("jdbc").option("driver", jdbc_driver_name).option("dbtable", table_name).option("url", db_url).option("user", db_username).option("password", db_password).load()
print(df)
df.printSchema()
print(df.count())

job.commit()
```

can anyone please give some inputs on this to work out. Thank you.

Exceptions i am getting

```
22/11/16 09:35:11 ERROR GlueExceptionAnalysisListener: [Glue Exception Analysis] {
    "Event": "GlueETLJobExceptionEvent",
    "Timestamp": 1668591311033,
    "Failure Reason": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/tmp/Glue2Db2.py\", line 24, in <module>\n    df = glueContext.read.format(\"jdbc\").option(\"driver\", jdbc_driver_name).option(\"dbtable\", table_name).option(\"url\", db_url).option(\"user\", db_username).option(\"password\", ).load()\n  File \"/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py\", line 210, in load\n    return self._df(self._jreader.load())\n  File \"/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py\", line 1305, in __call__\n    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)\n  File \"/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py\", line 111, in deco\n    return f(*a, **kw)\n  File \"/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py\", line 328, in get_return_value\n    format(target_id, \".\", name), value)\npy4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o102.load.\n: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.DisconnectNonTransientConnectionException: [jcc][t4][2043][11550][4.26.14] Exception java.net.ConnectException: Error opening socket to server cbfnd847/10.251.24.123 on port 50,000 with message: Connection timed out (Connection timed out). ERRORCODE=-4499, SQLSTATE=08001\n\tat com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.b7.a(b7.java:338)\n\tat com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.b7.a(b7.java:435)\n\tat com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.a0.a(a0.java:450)\n\tat com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.a0.<init>(a0.java:96)\n\tat com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.a.b(a.java:366)\n\tat com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.newAgent_(b.java:2164)\n\tat com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.Connection.initConnection(Connection.java:839)\n\tat com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:784)\n\tat com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.<init>(b.java:350)\n\tat com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2SimpleDataSource.getConnection(DB2SimpleDataSource.java:233)\n\tat com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2SimpleDataSource.getConnection(DB2SimpleDataSource.java:200)\n\tat com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver.connect(DB2Driver.java:471)\n\tat com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver.connect(DB2Driver.java:113)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.connection.BasicConnectionProvider.getConnection(BasicConnectionProvider.scala:49)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.connection.ConnectionProvider$.create(ConnectionProvider.scala:68)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.$anonfun$createConnectionFactory$1(JdbcUtils.scala:62)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD$.resolveTable(JDBCRDD.scala:56)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRelation$.getSchema(JDBCRelation.scala:226)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:35)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:354)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:326)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$3(DataFrameReader.scala:308)\n\tat scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:308)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:226)\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\n\tat sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\n\tat java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)\n\tat py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)\n\tat py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)\n\tat py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)\n\tat py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)\n\tat py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)\n\tat py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)\nCaused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)\n\tat java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)\n\tat java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)\n\tat java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)\n\tat java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)\n\tat java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)\n\tat java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607)\n\tat com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.x.run(x.java:49)\n\tat java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)\n\tat com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.a0.a(a0.java:436)\n\t... 33 more\n",
    "Stack Trace": [
        {
            "Declaring Class": "get_return_value",
            "Method Name": "format(target_id, \".\", name), value)",
            "File Name": "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py",
            "Line Number": 328
        },
        {
            "Declaring Class": "deco",
            "Method Name": "return f(*a, **kw)",
            "File Name": "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py",
            "Line Number": 111
        },
        {
            "Declaring Class": "__call__",
            "Method Name": "answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)",
            "File Name": "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py",
            "Line Number": 1305
        },
        {
            "Declaring Class": "load",
            "Method Name": "return self._df(self._jreader.load())",
            "File Name": "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py",
            "Line Number": 210
        },
        {
            "Declaring Class": "<module>",
            "Method Name": "df = glueContext.read.format(\"jdbc\").option(\"driver\", jdbc_driver_name).option(\"dbtable\", table_name).option(\"url\", db_url).option(\"user\", db_username).option(\"password\", ).load()",
            "File Name": "/tmp/Glue2Db2.py",
            "Line Number": 24
        }
    ],
    "Last Executed Line number": 24,
    "script": "Glue2Db2.py"
}
```

Comment: Not enough facts in your question. Many possible causes. please edit your question with the __full__ text of the exception (it should include the jdbc driver version).  It is important to get the db2jcc4.jar only from IBM with a version that is compatible with the Db2-server version.  Please add details of your Db2-server platform and version (z/os, linux/unix/windows, i-series). If connecting to Db2 for Z/OS or i-series, this requires licensing.  Verify your hostname (that is running python) can connect to the target Db2 independently of jdbc (for example, with odbc/cli).

Comment: Hi @mao, i added exception in the question

Comment: Please answer all the clarifications mentioned above, otherwise you waste everyones time. The failure is "connection timed out".  This can happen when your port-number is incorrect, or there is no route between client and Db2-server, or a firewall (incl. software firewall) is blocking traffic on the port. Always a configuration matter locally.  Not a programming matter.